# What return type do I make this method?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

Ive got the following code that returns a set of results from the CRM and then I bind it to a dropDownList:

```
        var context = new XrmServiceContext();
        var contacts1 =
            (
                from c in context.ContactSet
                join m in context.py3_membershipSet on c.ContactId equals m.py3_Member.Id
                where m.statuscode.Value == 1

                orderby c.LastName
                select new
                {
                    ContactId = c.ContactId,
                    FirstName = c.FirstName,
                    LastName = c.LastName,
                    BranchCode = c.py3_BranchArea,
                    Branch = (c.FormattedValues != null && c.FormattedValues.Contains("py3_brancharea") ? c.FormattedValues["py3_brancharea"] : "N/a"),
                    JobTitle = c.JobTitle,
                    Organisation = (c.ParentCustomerId != null ? c.ParentCustomerId.Name : "N/a"),
                    joinedAsCode = c.py3_SOLACEMemberJoinedAs,
                    JoinedAs = (c.FormattedValues != null && c.FormattedValues.Contains("py3_solacememberjoinedas") ? c.FormattedValues["py3_solacememberjoinedas"] : "N/a"),
                    Expertise = (c.py3_SOLACEMemberAreasofExpertise != null && c.py3_SOLACEMemberAreasofExpertise.Trim() != String.Empty ? c.py3_SOLACEMemberAreasofExpertise : "N/a")
                }
            );
```

However, I need to make this into a method so that I can can call this set of results and do some LINQ on the returned data depending on some other criteria.

Im new to using LINQ and the whole idea of 'var' to contain the result set, hence Im lost as to what type to make the method:

```
        protected static **something** getContacts()
    {
        var context = new XrmServiceContext();
        var contacts1 =
            (
                from c in context.ContactSet
                join m in context.py3_membershipSet on c.ContactId equals m.py3_Member.Id
                where m.statuscode.Value == 1

                orderby c.LastName
                select new
                {
                    ContactId = c.ContactId,
                    FirstName = c.FirstName,
                    LastName = c.LastName,
                    BranchCode = c.py3_BranchArea,
                    Branch = (c.FormattedValues != null && c.FormattedValues.Contains("py3_brancharea") ? c.FormattedValues["py3_brancharea"] : "N/a"),
                    JobTitle = c.JobTitle,
                    Organisation = (c.ParentCustomerId != null ? c.ParentCustomerId.Name : "N/a"),
                    joinedAsCode = c.py3_SOLACEMemberJoinedAs,
                    JoinedAs = (c.FormattedValues != null && c.FormattedValues.Contains("py3_solacememberjoinedas") ? c.FormattedValues["py3_solacememberjoinedas"] : "N/a"),
                    Expertise = (c.py3_SOLACEMemberAreasofExpertise != null && c.py3_SOLACEMemberAreasofExpertise.Trim() != String.Empty ? c.py3_SOLACEMemberAreasofExpertise : "N/a")
                }
            );

return contacts;
    }
```

What type should it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it's an anonymous type, so you can't specify a name. Any of the following will work:

- `IEnumerable`
- `IQueryable`
- `IEnumerable<dynamic>`
- `IQueryable<dynamic>`

However, I suggest making a simple POCO class to store your data instead and returning an `IQueryable<T>` of that.

```
public class GetContactsResult
{
    public long ContactId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    ...
}

protected static IQueryable<GetContactsResult> getContacts()
{
    ...
    var contacts =
        (from c in context.ContactSet
         ...
         select new GetContactsResult()
         {
             ...
         });
    return contacts;
}
```

Comment: Ok, but as I said Im fairly new to this so your answer means next to nothing of value to me. But, thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: @PhillHealey Invest time and effort to understanding the answers to your questions. Saying an answer is worth nothing to you, directly makes your question worth nothing to you (or us) as well.

Comment: I agree with p.s.w.g on making an explicit poco class instead of an anonymous

Comment: @PhillHealey I've tried to add sufficient information to my answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous types were specifically designed to be used only in the context in which they were created.  While it's possible to use one of several different techniques for returning the anonymous type, whatever you do will result in a loss of the compiler verified static typing, and will (in most cases) result in a performance hit as well.

By far the easiest, most effective, simplest, and least error prone solution is to create a new named type, rather than relying on an anonymous type.  Once you have created a new simple type with properties for each of those fields you can select a new instance of that type, rather than an anonymous one.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand that. But, how would I go about creating a named type within the bounds of my scenario? Thanks.

Comment: @PhillHealey The same way you create any other class... `public class MyClassName{ public int ContactId{get;set;} /* ... */ }`

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous types have a method scope. This means that if you pass an anonymous type outside the containing method boundary, then you have to cast it as an object. This means your only option is to use an object as return type.

You could use reflection as an alternative (but it's getting ugly):

```
static void ContainingMethod()
{
  var anondata = new
  {
    IntegerVal = 1,
    DoubleVal = 2.0D,
    DateTimeVal = DateTime.Now,
    StringVal = "some string"       
  };

  ExternalMethod(anondata);
}

static void ExternalMethod(object data)
{
  // Get the type that was passed in
  Type t = data.GetType();
  // Get a list of the properties
  PropertyInfo[] piList = t.GetProperties();
  // Loop through the properties in the list
  foreach (PropertyInfo pi in piList)
  {
    // Get the value of the property
    object o = pi.GetValue(data, null);
    // Write out the property information
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}): \t{2}", pi.Name, o.GetType(), o.ToString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is an anonymous type, I recommend you to create a class for that, for example:

```
class Person {

private int age;
private String name;
private String address;
//theirs respective getters and setters

}
```

then you'd be able to create a linq expression with the Person type

Comment: Thanks. That sounds interesting but might naivety means I dont yet know how to do that.